# How to prevent Git to delete dynamically created folders on openshift deploy?

Tags: git, flask, openshift

I am trying to deploy a FLASK application on Openshift, however since I do it via GIT, every time I do a `push` to the repo, I loose my `mediastorage` directory which is dynamically created, with subfolders depending on the actual month and year, and then images are saved in those folders.

There's any way to prevent this via GIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the directory manually and then just run

```
$cd mediastorage
$touch .gitkeep
```

Comment: Note that there's nothing special about the `.gitkeep` file. This isn't a magic name or anything; Git simply doesn't track empty directories.

Comment: I have already tried to create the dir manually, then added a `.gitignore` file, which served the same purpose, but didn't work. Every git push just deletes the dir with the images already saved.

Comment: I have find the openshift doc where they suggest to use a specific data directory which can be accessed via the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable, so after creating the deploy hook to use a symlink it worked. Thank you for the help @niharvey and @Chris!

Comment: @Kornel could you please share what you found, because I have the same problem and I can't find a solution!

Comment: @evolquez I was unable to use .gitkeep to maintain the directories through deployment, so I basically followed their suggestions on using the specified env variables pointing to specific storage directories.

Comment: @Kornel are you talking about OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR env variable?